# How can get data from table using REST API

Tags: php, rest, slim

I want to make rest API in php using Slim framework.

I have created a function to get all entries of my table like this:-

```
<?php

   header('Content-type: application/json');

  // Include the Slim library
  require 'Slim/Slim.php';

  // Instantiate the Slim class
  $app = new Slim();

  // Create a GET-based route
  $app->get('/', function () {
    echo "Pericent is working on Campus Concierge...";
  });

$app->get('/schools', function () 
{ 

    $sql = "SELECT * from school";

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Query error: " . mysql_error());

    $records = array();
    if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0)
     {

        echo '('.'['.json_encode(array('id' => 0)).']'.')';
     }
     else
     {
       while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
       {

           $records[] = $row;
       }

           echo json_encode($records);
     }

});
?>
```

Now i want to make a function which returns detail of school which id is **5**. so please suggest me how can make a function  so i can access school detain which id is given in url like this

```
192.168.1.126/schools/:5
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem by using some tutorials.

This is my solution:

```
$app->get('/schools/:id', function ($id) {

// Retrieve game associated with an ID of $id  
$sql = "SELECT * from school where schoolId='$id'";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Query error: " . mysql_error());

$records = array();
if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0)
 {

  echo '('.'['.json_encode(array('id' => 0)).']'.')';
 }
 else
 {
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
   {

     $records[] = $row;
   }

   echo json_encode($records);
 }
});
```

I hope this will help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

I posted some similar information on your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846968/fetch-data-from-table-using-rest-api/9077092#9077092). I highly recommend using object relational mapping for your DB stuff. It made my life super easy. Sounds like you already know SQL so you should be able to pick it up in a breeze. The documentation is solid. Check out this code that does what you want. [Idiorm/Paris](http://j4mie.github.com/idiormandparis/)

```
class School extends Model {}

$app->get('/school/:id', function($id) use ($app) {

    $school = Model::factory('School')->find_one($id);  // Paris: row with $id
    $schoolAry = $school->as_array('id', 'name', 'zip', 'numStudents');

    $response = $app->response();    // Slim Response object at work
    $response['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';

    echo json_encode($schoolAry);    // Output
});
```

Once you have your GET, POST, PUT, DELETE routers in place, you just use the easy features of Paris and you don't have to worry about long error prone query strings. :-)